# Spring Data Rest + ResourceProcessor

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I have a ResourceProcessor which shall add a link to a certain PersistentEntityResource (Foo).
The problem is that it kicks in for EVERY PersistentEntityResource in my project which ends in ClassCastExceptions.
When I create a new project with only 2 entities and repositories the processor works fine and only for the Entity which it implements as target.

My question is: What can cause SDR to use this Processor for every PersistentEntityResource and not only for the once for which it is implemented?

```
    @Component
    public class FooResourceProcessor implements ResourceProcessor<Resource<Foo>> {

     @Override
     public Resource<Foo> process(Resource<Foo> resource) {
       resource.add(new Link("/foooooooo"));
       return resource;
     }
```

I use Spring Boot 1.5.4

Comment: I've checked this issue in my demo [project](https://github.com/Cepr0/restdemo/blob/master/src/main/java/restsdemo/example12/OneResourceProcessor.java) - all works fine. 'ResourceProcessor' processed only `One` entity. Checked on 1.5.4 and 1.4.3 versions of SB.

Comment: Yes, I know that it works in a simple project. Therefore I want to know what can cause the error I have...

Comment: What do you mean 'simple project'? In this project there are a lot of entities. I have another, almost '[work project](https://github.com/Cepr0/restvotes)', and ResourceProcessor works as expected there.

Comment: I mean a project with just two entities, SDR, Spring Security. The project with the error uses a lot of other libs (aop etc pp). Something must cause this error.